# Rename all files in a user specified directory

Tags: c++, algorithm, directory, file-rename, std-filesystem

So I want to be able to automatically rename all files in a user specified directory (I am aware that c++ is not the optimum language/tool for doing this).

For example, a directory currently contains hundreds of files with random character names, and I wish to change them all to

> August 1, August 2, August 3 etc.

**The code**

*User specifies directory like this*

```
std::string directory;

std::cout << "Enter directory: ";
std::cin >> directory;
```

*Directory is opened like this* (using **`dirent.h`**)

```
DIR* pdir = NULL;
struct dirent* pent = NULL;
const char* DIRECTORY;

// convert directory string to const char
DIRECTORY = directory.c_str();

pdir = opendir(DIRECTORY);
```

*Rename all files within the specified directory here*

```
int i = 1;
std::string s, oldname, newname;
const char* OLDNAME, * NEWNAME;

while (pent = readdir(pdir))
{
    // convert int i to str s
    std::stringstream out;
    out << i;
    s = out.str();

    oldname = pent->d_name;
    newname = "August " + s;

    OLDNAME = oldname.c_str();
    NEWNAME = newname.c_str();

    rename(OLDNAME, NEWNAME);

    i++;
}
```

Everything works up until the while loop, which appears to do absolutely nothing, that is the part that I am stuck on.

However, the strange part is, that this while loop designed to display the contents of the directory (using same logic and syntax as nonworking loop) works perfectly

```
while (pent = readdir (pdir))
{
    std::cout << pent->d_name << "\n";
}
```

Using *MSVS2012* on *Win7*.

---

Another issue that I think I am going to run into is, within the directory, different files have different extensions (this may be able to be solved by saving the last 4 characters of the original name and appending it to the new name, but not sure, help would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: I would think you may be running into permissions problems ... have you tried to run your program as an administrator?

Answer (score 3):

Using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem), one can do nowadays, something like the followings. I hope that might be helpful for the future readers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>  //std::filesystem::path, std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator

std::string changeFileName(const std::string& currentFileName, const std::string& extension, int number)
{
   std::cout << "Current file name: " << currentFileName << "\n";

   // ....other logics regarding current filename

   const std::string newFileName{ "August - " + std::to_string(number) + extension};    
   std::cout << "File name after renaming: " << newFileName << "\n";
   return newFileName; // new file name
}

int main()
{
   const std::filesystem::path myPath = ".....full path....";
   const std::string extension{ ".txt" };
   int number{ 0 };
   // iterate through all the files in the directory
   for (const auto& dirEntry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(myPath))
   {
      // if the file is meant for changing name!
      if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(dirEntry) && dirEntry.path().extension() == extension)
      {
         const std::string currentFileName{ dirEntry.path().filename().string() };
         // following function is meant for the logic to provide the new file names in the directory
         // in your case it cout have been simply: "August - " + std::to_string(number++) + "extension"
         const std::string newFileName{ changeFileName(currentFileName, extension, number++) };
         try
         {
            std::filesystem::rename(myPath / currentFileName, myPath / newFileName);
         }
         catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& error)  // catch the errors(if any)!
         {
            std::cout << error.code() << "\n" << error.what() << "\n";
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pent->d_name` is just the file name without the associated path. So when you do *rename*, the program will look for `oldname` in the current directory and since it doesn't exist in this directory, *rename* doesn't do anything. To solve this you should append the path to both `oldname` and `newname`, for example:

```
oldname = (std::string(DIRECTORY)+pent->d_name).c_str();
newname = (std::string(DIRECTORY)+"August " + s).c_str();
```